# How to kill all the `buffers` in emacs at once?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a command to kill all buffers in my emacs? instead of having me doing 'Ctrl -k ' one by one until there is no more buffer?

Thank you.

Comment: the quick hackish way would be a keyboard macro. C-x C-( C-x C-k <ENTER> C-x C-) C-u 0 <f4>, then C-g after a while since it'll get stuck on killing the *scratch* buffer repeatedly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using this function to kill all the buffers in emacs

```
(defun nuke-all-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (mapcar 'kill-buffer (buffer-list))
  (delete-other-windows))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x K") 'nuke-all-buffers)
```

Works fine for me :-)

Comment: You can just say `'kill-buffer` instead of `(lambda (x) (kill-buffer x))`.

Comment: Can we do this by calling it outside of the emacs-deamon inside the terminal?

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>
<kbd>t</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

I highly recommend binding <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd> to `ibuffer` as a replacement for the default binding:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

(I've also bound my <kbd><menu></kbd> key to `ibuffer`, as I use it so often.)

n.b. You can use <kbd>C-k</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> in the regular `list-buffers` to mark and kill buffers, but I think everyone should be using `ibuffer`, really.

Answer (score 1):

Highly hack-ish, but does what you want:

```
(defun my-kill-everything ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (cur (buffer-list))
    (kill-buffer cur)))
```

Note that Emacs always needs at least one buffer, so you'll end up with an empty scratch buffer again. (Yes, this command also kills stuff like the minibuffer, but it will be restored. As I've written: highly hack-ish.)

Answer (score 0):

In Doom Emacs, there is also a function `doom/kill-all-buffers` which is bound to `SPC q F` and `SPC b K` by default.